# Cant get swig %ignore to ignore class in namespace resulting in compile error

Tags: python, c++, swig

I have a class declared in a header that's giving compile errors when run through swig:

```
namespace nsA
{
    namespace nsB
    {

#define DISABLE_COPYING_AND_ASSIGNING(ClassName) ClassName(const ClassName&) = delete; \
    ClassName& operator=(const ClassName&) = delete         

            class myClass
            {
            public:
                DISABLE_COPYING_AND_ASSIGNING(myClass);

                myClass(myClass_t opaque);

                myClass(myClass&& other);

                ~myClass();

                uint32_t myMethod() const;                

            private:
                myClass_t mOpaque;                
            };

            enum class myEnum
            {
               A= 0,
               B= 1
            };
    }
}
```

If I leave this class in the namespace I get this error:

> Error C2280   'nsA::nsB::myClass::myClass(const nsA::nsB::myClass &)': attempting to reference a deleted function

Here's what I've tried in the swig config file:

```
%ignore nsA::nsB::myClass; // Doesn't work

%ignore *myClass; // Doesn't work
```

I've also tried ignoring everything and unignoring other elements in the namespace but doesn't work either:

```
%ignore nsA::nsB; // This works to ignore the entire namespace

%rename("%s") nsA::nsB::myEnum;  // This does not work to re-include the struct
```

1. Why does the error point to nsA::nsB::myClass::myClass instead of
   nsA::nsB::myClass?
2. Any hints on what's causing swig to cause this
   error?
3. What am I doing wrong when trying to ignore/uningore classes
   in swig?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't actually an issue with the namespace. SWIG is trying to call the copy constructor of `nsA::nsB::myClass` (which is called `nsA::nsB::myClass::myClass`) in the wrapped code.

SWIG can't handle move-only classes, as far as I can tell. See https://github.com/swig/swig/issues/999 for updates.